# How to start the automatically stopped android service?

Tags: android, service

I have written a service, it runs at start up, but suddenly due to some run time errors the service is stopping. How can I re run the automatically stopped service  (because of run time exception).

Comment: Have you considered fixing the `RuntimeException` that is causing your service to stop?

Comment: Does your service onStartCommand return START_STICKY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a

```
stopSelf()
stopSelf(startId)
```

method in service which you can use to stop a service from inside.

**EDIT**

**i guess i need some rest.**

well if you want to find if a service is stopping due to some runtimeexecption

can you try

```
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler onRuntimeError= new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            //Try starting the service again
                    //May be a pending intent might work
    };
```

in your on create

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(onRuntimeError);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could get a second service that monitors the first service, and restarts it if its stops responding. I think that is basically what the watchdog in Android does for the system-services.