# Restart application if app crash or ram clear or android os release memory of the app

Tags: android, crash, application-restart

I want to restart application if there is a crash issue or ram clear or release of memory which will ultimately clear variables and NPE will occur.

I have tried [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275339/android-application-crashes-when-ram-memory-cleared)  and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224954/restart-app-after-crash-programmatically-android) and,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(onRuntimeError);
    }

    /*
     * To handle the crash issues, and restart from the last state.
     */
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler onRuntimeError = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try {

                Log.e(TAG, "App crash");
                // Try starting the Activity again
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SplashScreenActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.e(TAG, "App crash2");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But in all cases neither app restart nor toast message appears, only white screen appears and logs are also printed.

Does [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) only useful for reporting logs or it also take some extra care of application restarting or preventing ANR?